# Binding library for Xamarin iOS is throwing a Native Linking Error when included in a project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding, xamarin.ios

We are trying to use [Flic buttons](https://flic.io/). They do not have any .Net libraries, so we're creating binding libraries. The libraries compile, but when they are referenced by the Xamarin.Forms project and we build iOS, it throws the following errors:

```
Native linking failed. Please review the build log.
Native linking error: framework not found fliclib.1.2.2.PBF.PROD
```

Any idea how we get passed this?

Comment: `...when they are referenced by the Xamarin.Forms project...` You mean referenced by the `Xamarin.iOS` application project...right?

Comment: @SushiHangover, yes. I mean to say the iOS project in the forms solution.

Comment: Cool... Are you trying to compile for the simulator or device as the last time I bound Flic they do not support x86_xx (they had some ObjC sim stubs for Xcode but they of course would not work for Xamarin)

Comment: @SushiHangover I am compiling for a physical device

Comment: @GarrettDanielDeMeyer I also faced similar issue with binding library linking. However you can try adding the mentioned framework to the native references in the iOS project. In my scenario also I got the similar error and added the framework to the native references and it worked

Comment: @hashimks, sorry I forgot to update the question. I believe this was the solution.

Comment: Shall I post it as answer?

Comment: @hashimks sure! I'll accept it if you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding the .framework which is mentioned in the error description to the native references of the Xamarin iOS project. This will resolve the framework link issues.